# What is the method for finding the reciprocal lattice vectors in this 2D lattice?

Tags: vectors, physics, mathematical-physics

> Consider a rectangular lattice in two dimensions with primitive lattice vectors $(a,0)$ and $(0,2a)$.
>
> Which of the following are reciprocal lattice vectors for this lattice?
>
> (a) $\quad\dfrac{\pi}{a}\left(1,\frac12 \right)$
>
> (b) $\quad\dfrac{\pi}{a}\left(1,2 \right)$
>
> (c) $\quad\dfrac{\pi}{a}\left(2,-1 \right)$
>
> (d) $\quad\dfrac{\pi}{a}\left(0,2 \right)$
>
> (e) $\quad\dfrac{\pi}{a}\left(\frac12,-2 \right)$

---

So we have $$\vec a_1 = a\hat i$$ and $$\vec a_2 = 2a\hat j$$ and $$\vec a_3=\hat k$$ since I am going to be using the 3-dimensional formulue for the reciprocal lattice vectors:

$$\vec b_1 =2\pi\frac{\vec a_2 \times \vec a_3}{\vec a_1\cdot(\vec a_2 \times \vec a_3)},\quad\vec b_2 =2\pi\frac{\vec a_3 \times \vec a_1}{\vec a_1\cdot(\vec a_2 \times \vec a_3)},\quad\vec b_3 =2\pi\frac{\vec a_1 \times \vec a_2}{\vec a_1\cdot(\vec a_2 \times \vec a_3)}$$

For a 2D lattice, I was told that

> If you want to use the 3D definition with the cross products to deduce the $\vec b$ vectors, choose $\vec a_3 = \hat k$.

This is something my lecturer told me and is in my lecture notes.

So I start by computing $$\vec a_2 \times \vec a_3=
        \begin{vmatrix}
        \hat i & \hat j & \hat k \\
        0 & 2a & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{vmatrix}=2a\hat i,\,\,\,\,\,\vec a_3 \times \vec a_1=
        \begin{vmatrix}
        \hat i & \hat j & \hat k \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        a & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{vmatrix}=a\hat j,\,\,\,\,\,\vec a_1 \times \vec a_2=
        \begin{vmatrix}
        \hat i & \hat j & \hat k \\
        a & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 2a & 0 \\
        \end{vmatrix}=2a^2\hat k $$

Substituting these results into the formulue for the reciprocal lattice vectors gives 
$$\vec b_1 =2\pi\frac{2a\hat i}{a\hat i\cdot\Big(2a\hat i\Big)},\quad\vec b_2 =2\pi\frac{a\hat j}{a\hat i\cdot\Big(2a\hat i\Big)},\quad\vec b_3 =2\pi\frac{2a^2\hat k}{a\hat i\cdot\Big(2a\hat i\Big)}$$
Since $\hat i^2=$ unity, and all the denominators are identical; on simplification this gives
$$\vec b_1 =2\pi\frac{2a\hat i}{2a^2},\quad\vec b_2 =2\pi\frac{a\hat j}{2a^2},\quad\vec b_3 =2\pi\frac{2a^2\hat k}{2a^2}$$ and so

$$\vec b_1 =\frac{2\pi}{a}\hat i,\quad\vec b_2 =\frac{\pi}{a}\hat j,\quad\vec b_3 =2\pi\,\hat k$$

---

I know $\vec b_3 =2\pi\,\hat k$ cannot be valid as the choices in the question do not contain a $z$ component. But that's the first problem, the other thing is that the only combination of $\vec b_1$ and $\vec b_2$ I can make is $$\dfrac{\pi}{a}\left(2,1 \right)$$ which does not correspond to any of the choices in the question.

**The two correct answers are (c) and (d).**

Could someone please explain to me how to find reciprocal lattice vectors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there. Any reciprocal lattice vector can be written as $\vec{v}=m\vec{b}_1+n\vec{b}_2$, where $m$ and $n$ are integers. By plugging in what you obtained for $\vec{b}_1$ and $\vec{b}_2$, you get $\vec{v}=\frac{\pi}{a}(2n,m)$. So the first element is an even integer (answers a,b,e are wrong) and the second element is an integer (answer a is wrong).

Note that the easier way to compute your reciprocal lattice vectors is $\vec{a}_i\cdot\vec{b}_j=2\pi\delta_{ij}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry it took a while for me to respond. You mention that "the easier way to compute your reciprocal lattice vectors is $\vec{a}_i\cdot\vec{b}_j=2\pi\delta_{ij}$". So if I chose $\vec a_1 = a\hat i$ and wrote $a\hat i \cdot \vec {b}_1=2\pi\delta_{ij}$. With an unknown $\vec {b}_1$ how would I proceed? Could you please show me in your answer how to compute reciprocal lattice vectors in this manner? Many thanks.

Comment: $\vec{b}_1=(x,y)$. Then $\vec{a}_1\cdot \vec{b}_1=ax$. This means $x=2\pi/a$. If  $\vec{a}_2=(0,2a)$ then $\vec{a}_2\cdot \vec{b}_1=2ay=0$ so $y=0$. You do the same vor $\vec{b}_2$